# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ExNull) doesn't show when deployed to Weblogic server

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ExNull)` in my module.

`Exnull` is the `SQLException` in trapping in the catch block.

My issue here is when tested the same on Tomcat server, `JOptionPane` works great, but when the same is deployed on Weblogic server, the pop-out doesn't seems to pop-out.

Can anyone please help in here, or suggest an alternative for this?

The error I am getting is:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:431)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1673)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:846)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:650)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:621)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:592)
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing a web application you should not use a GUI to report errors. Apparently WebLogic even disallows this by running in headless mode (i.e. no GUI elements can be shown).

The usual way of reporting errors in a server application is logging it (for example writing the stack trace to a file). There are many logging libraries around (e.g. [Apache commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/), [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) or [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)) and a simple one is even in the core API of Java, see the [API documentation of the `java.util.logging` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).

**EDIT:** If you really want to show a GUI (I recommend against it) it should be possible to modify the WebLogic configuration: Look for `-Djava.awt.headless=true` and change it to `false`.

Depending on what you would like to do there are multiple alternative workarounds you could consider:

- If you want to debug something "quick and dirty", you could simply write it out to `System.out`.
- If you want to manage or monitor your web application, you could create a special administration page in your web application. So you don't need a separate GUI as you can access this administration page with your browser like you do with the rest of your application.
- A other possibility would be to create a complete separate application and let it communicate with your web application (e.g. by connecting to some administration/monitoring/debug port).

The last two workarounds would also give you the possibility to monitor your web application from your developer machine without the need to remote control the server.

Comment: any workaroudn for this ? let's say you are doing this because you want to investigate somethign